# Elegant way to search an PHP array using a user-defined function

Tags: php, collections, functional-programming

Basically, I want to be able to get the functionality of C++'s `find_if()`, Smalltalk's `detect:` etc.:

```
// would return the element or null
check_in_array($myArray, function($element) { return $elemnt->foo() > 10; });
```

But I don't know of any PHP function which does this. One "approximation" I came up with:

```
$check = array_filter($myArray, function($element) { ... });
if ($check) 
    //...
```

The downside of this is that the code's purpose is not immediately clear. Also, it won't stop iterating over the array even if the element was found, although this is more of a nitpick (if the data set is large enough to cause problems, linear search won't be an answer anyway)

Comment: Don't you have to do the exact same thing in C++/Smalltalk/etc anyway, on the condition it wasn't found?  Or are you assuming there'll always be at least one result?

Comment: It looks like you're looking for PHP equivalent of JS (ES5, to be precise) [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method - but this method returns boolean, not an object.

Comment: Boolean return would be ok as well. @Izkata: Yes, you're right of course, you can only stop iterating if there is a result - so it's kind of a special case anyway. My bad.

Comment: Sometimes I temped to used such a function, but a standard `foreach` in a log of locations yield more concise an more readable code.

Answer (score -91, accepted):

You can write your own function ;)

```
function callback_search ($array, $callback) { // name may vary
    return array_filter($array, $callback);
}
```

This maybe seems useless, but it increases semantics and can increase readability

Comment: Good point about readability/semantics, and I like the simplicity of this. I'm usually not a fan of keeping my own "standard library enhancements" around, but if I keep stumbling upon this, I might give it a go.

Comment: `callback_search` is *exactly the same* as `array_filter` in this case. Any call to `callback_search` can be safely replaced with `array_filter`; they are equal.

Comment: @BenjaminKovach Read my comment: "This maybe seems useless, but it increases semantics and can increase readability". The author is aware of the equality :)

Comment: `array_filter` is formally documented, though! Wrapping existing functions in new names for the sake of readability is just asking for unreadable, unmaintainable code, which comes first.

Comment: @BenjaminKovach Having a simple and self-explaining function/method signature is more worth than a link to a documentation somewhere in the web. Additionally the identifier name can include the _intention_, which isn't possible when you use general purpose functions. Think of `substr($x, 0, 3) == 'foo'` vs `startsWith($x, 'foo')`. I must admit, that the example above isn't the best one though. But on the other hand it's two years old ;)

Comment: @KingCrunch `startsWith` is a different function.

Comment: It's still not a good solution as it won't stop searching once it finds a match.

Comment: @demonkoryu It works in most cases and the cases, where you _measure_ a slowdown you should of course use an optimized solution. See the question: "Also, it won't stop iterating over the array even if the element was found, although this is more of a nitpick (if the data set is large enough to cause problems, linear search won't be an answer anyway)"

Comment: Nobody has mentioned how this will ruin autocomplete/suggestion/typehinting features in some text editors and IDEs

Comment: @Doctus Why should it?

Comment: This is the same as `array_filter`. ‍♂️

Answer (score 79):

To pull the first one from the array, or return `false`:

```
current(array_filter($myArray, function($element) { ... }))
```

[More info on current() here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php).

Comment: Neat, didn't know about current().

Comment: This has inefficient O(n) time complexity.

Comment: @QuolonelQuestions All answers will be `O(n)` unless there's been some preprocessing (sorting, hashing, etc)

Comment: @Izkata That's patently false. The search should stop once the element has been found. Your crude code continues to process every element regardless of when a match is found.

Comment: @QuolonelQuestions That's still `O(n)`, linear time complexity

Comment: A straightforward implementation with foreach would have `O(1)` best case, `O(n)` worst case. This is `O(n)` in both cases. Also, `O(n)` space complexity instead of `O(1)` (ie. the whole array might get duplicated in memory).

Comment: You can use you can use SPL iterators instead (PHP 5.4+): `(new CallbackFilterIterator(new ArrayIterator($myArray), function($element) { return $element->foo() > 10; }))->current()` although I don't think that meets a reasonable definition of "elegant".

Comment: If you want to pass your own argument into callback function, you could add "use" current(array_filter($myArray, function($element) use($my_param) { ... }))

Comment: @Tgr best case would be described as Ω(1)

Comment: `current()` is incomprehensible, unpredictable, stateful dark automagic from PHP/FI era. It should have been removed from the language a generation ago, and I mean human generation.

Comment: Just to add to the answer, for anyone coming from google - like me - if all you need is the key and not the element, swap the `current` with the `key` function, like this: `key(array_filter($myArray, function($element) { ... })))`

Answer (score 64):

Here's a basic solution

```
function array_find($xs, $f) {
  foreach ($xs as $x) {
    if (call_user_func($f, $x) === true)
      return $x;
  }
  return null;
}

array_find([1,2,3,4,5,6], function($x) { return $x > 4; });  // 5
array_find([1,2,3,4,5,6], function($x) { return $x > 10; }); // null
```

In the event `$f($x)` returns `true`, the loop short circuits and `$x` is immediately returned. Compared to `array_filter`, this is better for our use case because `array_find` does not have to continue iterating after the first positive match has been found.

In the event the callback never returns true, a value of `null` is returned.

---

Note, I used `call_user_func($f, $x)` instead of just calling `$f($x)`. This is appropriate here because it allows you to use any compatible [callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php)

```
Class Foo {
  static private $data = 'z';
  static public function match($x) {
    return $x === self::$data;
  }
}

array_find(['x', 'y', 'z', 1, 2, 3], ['Foo', 'match']); // 'z'
```

---

Of course it works for more complex data structures too

```
$data = [
  (object) ['id' => 1, 'value' => 'x'],
  (object) ['id' => 2, 'value' => 'y'],
  (object) ['id' => 3, 'value' => 'z']
];

array_find($data, function($x) { return $x->id === 3; });
// stdClass Object (
//     [id] => 3
//     [value] => z
// )
```

---

If you're using PHP 7, add some type hints

```
function array_find(array $xs, callable $f) { ...
```

Comment: Regarding your last piece of code, `array` and `callable` type hinting have been in PHP since [5.1.0 and 5.4.0](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration) respectively.

Comment: You don't need PHP 7 to add those type hints.

Comment: You can only hint selected types in older PHP. Writing inconsistent code isn't a recommendation I would make.

Comment: I know this is a minor nitpick and most people won't care, but I'd probably have called the arguments `$array` and `$comparator` so you can actually tell what they are from the signature. Definitely the most straight forward solution, and the one I tend to go with, though.

Answer (score 8):

The original `array_search` returns the key of the matched value, and not the value itself (this might be useful if you're will to change the original array later).

try this function (it also works will associatives arrays)

```
function array_search_func(array $arr, $func)
{
    foreach ($arr as $key => $v)
        if ($func($v))
            return $key;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I like this. FWIW, I named my version of this `first_key`, to remind myself that it returns the `key` not the `value`.

Answer (score 5):

Pulled from Laravel's `Illuminate\Collections\Arr::first` method:

```php
if (!function_exists('array_first')) {
    /**
     * Return the first element in an array passing a given truth test.
     *
     * @param  iterable  $array
     * @param  callable|null  $callback
     * @param  mixed  $default
     * @return mixed
     */
    function array_first($array, callable $callback = null, $default = null)
    {
        if (is_null($callback)) {
            if (empty($array)) {
                return $default;
            }

            foreach ($array as $item) {
                return $item;
            }
        }

        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            if ($callback($value, $key)) {
                return $value;
            }
        }

        return $default;
    }
}
```

I think it's pretty good. There is also the `Illuminate\Collections\Arr::last` method, but it's probably not as optimized since it reverses the array and just calls the `first` method. It does get the job done, though.

```php
if (!function_exists('array_last')) {
    /**
     * Return the last element in an array passing a given truth test.
     *
     * @param  array  $array
     * @param  callable|null  $callback
     * @param  mixed  $default
     * @return mixed
     */
    function array_last($array, callable $callback = null, $default = null)
    {
        if (is_null($callback)) {
            return empty($array) ? $default : end($array);
        }

        return array_first(array_reverse($array, true), $callback, $default);
    }
}
```

---

**Pro-tip**: If you have an array of objects, then you can specify the type of the callback's argument for that sweet IDE auto-completion.

```php
$john = array_first($users, function(User $user) {
    return $user->name === 'John';
});

// Works with pretty much anything.

$activeUsers = array_filter($users, function(User $user) {
    return $user->isActive;
});

// Class example:
class User {
    public string $name;
    public bool $isActive;
    //...
}
```

If you want to use some variable from the outer scope, you can use the `use(&$var)` syntax like this

```php
foreach($values as $key => $value) {
  array_find($conditionsRecords, function($row) use(&$key) {
    $keyToFind = $key;
    return $keyToFind;
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `\iter\search()` from nikic's [iter library](https://github.com/nikic/iter) of primitive iteration functions. It has the added benefit that it operates on both arrays *and* `Traversable` collections.

```
$foundItem = \iter\search(function ($item) {
    return $item > 10;
}, range(1, 20));

if ($foundItem !== null) {
    echo $foundItem; // 11
}
```

Comment: A good answer that involves an off-site resource references the following: What is this thing you're talking about? Where do I install it? How do I install it? How do I use this thing to solve the **exact problem** I have in my question? Are you affiliated with this thing in any way, shape, or form? See: [How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022)

Answer (score -1):

You can write such a function yourself, although it is little more than a loop.

For instance, this function allows you to pass a callback function. The callback can either return 0 or a value. The callback I specify returns the integer if it is > 10. The function stops when the callback returns a non null value.

```
function check_in_array(array $array, $callback)
{
  foreach($array as $item)
  {
    $value = call_user_func($callback, $item);
    if ($value !== null)
      return $value;
  }
}

$a = array(1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 11, 15);
echo check_in_array($a, function($i){ return ($i > 10?$i:null); });
```

Comment: I would prefer to do it in a way where I can simply return a Boolean from my $callback, since the callback becomes unnecessarily complex otherwise (imo). Another thing: You are relying on the callback to return the correct item here - is that intended? What if the callback returns something which is not even in the array - it would break the function's semantics.

Comment: No matter what it returns, as long as it is not null it breaks the loop. You could use false as well if you need to, but I think of false as an actual value. An example use would be to return the name of the first employee with a salary over 50000. You fill the array with employee objects, check `$i->salary` in the callback and return `$i->name`. Of course, if you don't want this, you can return `true` just as well. It all depends on you exact needs.

Comment: And an advantage of this one over wrapping `array_filter`, is that this loop is actually terminated as soon as an item is found, which can speed things up for larger arrays.

Comment: I actually think that wrapping array_filter will be faster. Why? array_filter is a built-in function, probably implemented directly in the interpreter and highly optimized. Writing your own loop will most certainly be slower (especially since it's interpreted). And the point about terminating early is only applicable if all your arrays actually have a match which is located somewhere close to the beginning.

Comment: It's not interpreted on each iteration. The PHP file is interpreted once and compiled into memory. The compiled version can even be cached if you have APC (which you probably have in a production environment). That aside, my function only loops through the array, while `array_filter` is actually generating a new array and returns that array. So even though it is internal, it does have to do extra work, (creating object, allocating memory, copying items) and it also does that work using your (just as interpreted) callback function for each item.

Comment: Good points.. Yes I know that the script is compiled once, but I'm pretty sure there will still be some advantage for built-in functions. You're totally right about invoking my (not built-in) callback function, of course. Would be interesting to compare the actual run times of both variants.