# Search needle in_array using a user-defined comparison function

Tags: php, arrays, search

After searching some question on SO about this issue I could only found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106304/search-in-php-array-with-a-custom-comparator) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224812/elegant-way-to-search-an-php-array-using-a-user-defined-function) but both do not allow sending argument (AKA needle) to the search function but using pre-defined function and using `array_filter`.

I search [`in_array` documentation](https://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) but found none.

I want to have something like (as [usort](https://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) enable):

```
function uin_array($haystack, $needle, $compareFunc)
```

I manage to implement it with simple `foreach` loop:

```
function uin_array($haystack, $needle, $compareFunc) {
    foreach($haystack as $e) {
        if ($compareFunc($needle, $e) == 0)
            return true;
    }    
    return false;
}
```

Example:

```
$found = uin_array(["AA", "BB", "CC", "DD"], "cc", "strcasecmp");
```

This could also be used in searching in the multi-dimension array.

**My question**:

Is there any built-in function/flag like this in PHP that I'm not aware of?
Is there any better way to implement it?

**Edit**:

I know I can use `array_filter` as: `current(array_filter($haystack, function($element) use ($needle) { ... }))` but that is O(n) in **all** cases - using loop and break or in_array may be O(1) in some case (will be O(n) in only in worst case but not all)

Comment: `array_filter`?

Comment: I know I can do something like `current(array_filter($haystack, function($element) use ($needle) { ... }))` but that is `O(n)` in all cases - using loop and break or `in_array` may be `O(1)` in some case (will be `O(n)` in only in worst case but not all)

Comment: The function you provided in your question is the best solution. Core php does not have any user-defined `in_array` variations.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at a great [nikic/iter library](https://github.com/nikic/iter).

```
$haystack = ["AA", "BB", "CC", "DD"];
$needle = "cc";

$found = \iter\any(function ($value) use ($needle) {
    return strcasecmp($needle, $value);
}, $haystack);
```

Comment: Best answer so far. I recommend editing it to `$found = \iter\any(function ($value) use ($needle, $compareFunc) { return $compareFunc($needle, $value); }, $haystack);` so the compare function can be argument and add `use iter\fn;` . Upvoted. I still waiting to see if better answer come up else will accept.

Comment: Yeah, if you want to be flexible with `$compareFunc`, see my second answer with `functional-php` lib example

Answer (score 1):

If you are not afraid of function currying, take a look at [functional-php library](http://github.com/lstrojny/functional-php).

```
use function Functional\partial_any;
use function Functional\some;
use function Functional\placeholder;

$haystack = ["AA", "BB", "CC", "DD"];
$needle = "cc";
$compareFunc = "strcasecmp";

$found = some($haystack, partial_any($compareFunc, $needle, placeholder()));
```

The library provides nice helpers to write code in more functional style, but I would advice you to use it in the whole project or not to use it at all, because requiring it only for one or two occasional uses doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, you can user either array_reduce or array_filter to return 0, 1 or more items that will match your criteria.

Comment: These functions will look through __all__ elements of array. While function which is already provided by OP will break after required item is found.

Comment: The idea behind my suggest is to go through all the elements of the array indeed. That way, if you have more than one match, you can find them all. If the intention is to just find the first match, then these won't well.

This question raises a legitimate need to have a PHP extension that does just that and that can later be brought into PHP core.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_map`,  `strcasecamp`, `array_filter`

```
$needle      = 'cc';
$compareFunc = 'strcasecmp';
$found    = count(array_filter(array_map(function($v) use ($needle,$compareFunc){
  if($compareFunc($v, $needle) == 0) return 1;
}, ["AA", "BB", "CC", "DD"])));
```

Comment: I know, I have example similar to that in the question (edit part). I am looking for more efficient solution then that. Currently @AlexeyShokov answer is the best but I am waiting to see if someone can come up with a better one

Comment: @dWinder you are talking about the user-defined comparison here, but in the solutoin, he is using strcasecmp as static ? Where can a user change the comparison function ?

Comment: I am guessing it could be used as: `$found = \iter\any(function ($value) use ($needle, $compareFunc) {
    return $compareFunc($needle, $value);
}, $haystack);`

Comment: I am not able to execute this getting "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function iter\any()"

Comment: i see, need to use the library