# How to search in an array of objects for an object with array_search?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array ($sensors) of objects. In this array I want to search for a sensor with an ID ($deviceId).
With a foreach loop it works. I get exactly one object. No array.
Now I'm looking for a solution with array_search. But it doesn't work. 
Does anyone have a solution?

```
$sensor = null;
foreach ($sensors as $item)
{
   if ($item->DeviceId == $deviceId)
   {
      $sensor = $item;
      break;
   }        
}
```

Comment: Can you add code or screenshot of your existing `array` format and desired output?

Comment: Do not use `array_search`, provided code is simple and clear.

Comment: This post may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55797796/search-needle-in-array-using-a-user-defined-comparison-function

Answer (score 0):

Object convert to array and search in array ,I cant see your all code but almost should code as below

```
 $array=json_decode(json_encode($object),true);

 $result=array_search($sensor,$array);

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if ( ($key = array_search($item->DeviceId, $sensors)) !== false) {
                echo $sensors[$key]);
}
```

Comment: `array_search` searches a value in array. How can it find value by it's property?